# IOS Safari html element does not honor width with scaled children

Tags: ios, css, safari, scale

I was trying to center an element in a div that had a transformation on it and noticed that the element would float off the page in iOS Safari only. Upon investigation, I believe the problem can be boiled down to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html style="width: 100%">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="child1" style="width: 100%"></div>
        <div id="child2" style="width: 100%; scale(2)"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You will find that the computed width on html and thereby child1 is 200%.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to set additional properties on the html style:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```